# How to eager load with model name instead of model itself in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following code:

```js
const service = await Service.findByPk(req.params.service_id, {
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      attributes: {
        exclude: ['password'],
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Is there any way for me to replace the model User with the name of the model, so I don't have to import the User model?

Comment: I'll post this as a comment because it's probably not the answer you're locking for, but depending on your configuration you may reference `User` from [`sequelize.models`](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-member-models) - sequelize being the ORM client instance you've constructed when connecting to your database and defining the models, which you can import if not already imported or [access via a model instance](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-get-sequelize)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1. You can use [sequelize.models](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-member-models) property.

> Models are stored here under the name given to `sequelize.define`

But you still need to import the instance of the `Sequelize` class.

```js
import { Service } from './models';
import { sequelize } from '../../db';

async function controller(req, res) {
  const service = await Service.findByPk(req.params.service_id, {
    include: [
      {
        model: sequelize.models['User'],
        attributes: {
          exclude: ['password'],
        },
      },
    ],
  });
}
```

`db.js`:

```js
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: 'postgres',
  //...
})

export { sequelize }
```

Option 2. You can use [Model.sequelize](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#instance-get-sequelize).

> A reference to the sequelize instance

In this way, you don't need to import the instance of the `Sequelize` class. You can get the instance from `Model.sequelize` property.

```js
import { Service } from './models';

async function controller(req, res) {
  const service = await Service.findByPk(req.params.service_id, {
    include: [
      {
        model: Service.sequelize.models['User'],
        attributes: {
          exclude: ['password'],
        },
      },
    ],
  });
}
```